# Selenium Java How do I keep the browser window open on a failed test step

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

Morning all (unless its afternoon/Evening where you are)

I have just started using Selenium on Eclipse and am creating my first automated test cases. Is there any way to stop the Browser window from closing on the event of a fail? Its very frustrating at the moment running a test and having it fail without knowing exactly why. I know that my test can be set up to take a screenshot of the failed step. However it would make life a lot easier for me if I could have the browser stay open so i can debug the failed step as at this moment in time any failure will be due to test error, not product failure. I am using Java to create my test scripts and my initial tests are being written for Chrome, however a non browser specific approach would be idea as eventually I will need to run these tests on all available browsers.

Thanks for your support

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Did you try not calling the `driver.quit()` option as the last command.

Browser will wait till you close it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use Exception handling (try,catch and throw) to handle the error. Test cases (or)events fails while running the script, it will ignore the errors and run continuously.If you want to catch the errors and stop the selenium script, use the following example.

```
try{
      driver.findElement(By.id("someid")).click();
   }
   catch(NoSuchElementException e)
   {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      driver.close();
      driver.quit();
   }
```

Comment: This is opposite what the OP is asking. He does not want to close the driver in case of exception.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood. You want to stop on the page where your script get failed. I have following things for that -

1. Comment the code where you have used `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()`
2. If you are using `try` `catch` block for the code where you expected to script failure and taken screenshot in `catch` block . Then you have to remove the `try catch` block because It is handling the exception where you expecting failure and further  continuing your code execution.
3. Run your script in Debug mode and analyse the fact.